# Is there a workaround for Qt 4.4 visual artefacts on Mac OS X 10.6 (snow leopard)

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, osx-snow-leopard

My software is written in Qt 4.4.2 using XCode on Mac OS X 10.5. It runs fine on Mac OS X 10.5. But when it is run on Mac OS X 10.6 it shows some strange visual artefacts when drawing the drop-down menus of QComboBoxes. Apparently it affects every QComboBox.

4 people with Mac OS X 10.6 who have tried it have reported the same behaviour, so it isn't a quirk on one machine. Everything else apparently looks fine.

The combo boxes function OK, but it doesn't look great. Aesthetics are important for commercial apps, especially on Mac OS X.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour with Qt apps on Mac OS X 10.6?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: It's probably worth trying the Qt support forums or directly with Qt support if you're on a commercial license.

Comment: I let my support lapse when the LGPL version of Qt came out.

I tried qt-interest. No luck so far.

Comment: I have now logged a bug with the Qt developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a patch:

http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/08/31/qt-46-on-mac-os-106/

But it appears to only partially address the problem on Qt 4.4. See:

http://successfulsoftware.net/2009/09/03/qt-visual-artefacts-on-mac-os-x-10-6/

Comment: A second patch, linked above, fixes the issue.